# Cassandra schema generation from existing Thrift or Hector object

Tags: java, cassandra, schema

I have a Java application which dynamically creates column families.
So I have a set of ThriftCfDef objects.
Which are created usually like:

```
ThriftCfDef sfDef = (ThriftCfDef) HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition(TestKeyspace, MYCOLUMNFAMILY, ComparatorType);
```

I.e. nothing special here...

But, is there any way (tool, library, framework) to generate cli or CQL commands for creating schema of existing ThriftCfDef java object??

There is a Cassandra-cli command "Show schema" which shows a cli script to create keyspaces and column families. I need something similar but from Java object -> script.file.